Why are does knowing the value of the PMCC count as two restrictions when working out degrees of freedom?
My understanding of degrees of freedom is it's the sample size - number of independent restrictions.
So I understand if we have 5 random numbers and know their mean then we are completely free to pick 4 numbers but the last one is determined by these four numbers hence $5-1=4$ degrees of freedom.
However, if we have $n$ pieces of bivariate data and we know the value of the PMCC then surely we can freely choose $n-1$ pieces of data and then work out what the value of the last piece of data need to be to give that PMCC? So I'm struggling to see why in a hypothesis test of the PMCC there are $n-2$ degrees of freedom.
Do I have an oversimplified understanding of what's going on?
